# How can I persist updated form data after submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, jwt

So I have some formdata in my react app that I want to persist after I make a put request to the mongodb. Problem is that the change is not visible on page refresh. It is only after I log out and log in again that I can see the updated value in the form.

For example let's say that I want to change my first name from John to Eric. The change will update but not in the form. In the form the value will still be John until I log out and in again.

It feels almost like it has to do with the jwt token but I don't know. Any ideas what the problem can be?

```
export const Edit = () => {
const navigate = useNavigate();
const user = Cookies.get("access_token");


 const [id, setId] = useState(null)
 const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("")
 const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("")
 const [city, setCity] = useState("")
 const [email, setEmail] = useState("")

  const checkUser = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}user/protected`, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${user}`,
                },
      })

        console.log(res.data.user);
        setId(res.data.user.id)
        setFirstName(res.data.user.firstName)
        setLastName(res.data.user.lastName)
        setCity(res.data.user.city)
        setEmail(res.data.user.email)
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error)
    }
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      navigate('/')
    } else {
      checkUser();
    }
  }, []);

  const updateUser = async () => {
    try {
      const userData = {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        city: city,
        email: email
      }

      const API_URL = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}user/`;
      const userId = id;
      
      const res = await axios.put(API_URL + "/" + userId + "/edit", userData)

      setFirstName(res.data.firstName)
      setLastName(res.data.lastName)
      setCity(res.data.city)
      setEmail(res.data.email)
      // works and is updated in the database
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error)
    }
  }

return (
    <>
      <section className="m-5">
        <h1 className="mb-5 text-center">Settings</h1>
        <form className="row g-3">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <label htmlFor="firstName" className="form-label">
              First name
            </label>
            <p>{formErrors.firstName}</p>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="firstName"
              name="firstName"
              value={firstName}
              onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-6">
            <label htmlFor="lastName" className="form-label">
              Last name
            </label>
            <p>{formErrors.lastName}</p>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="lastName"
              name="lastName"
              value={lastName}
              onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-6">
            <label htmlFor="city" className="form-label">
              City
            </label>
            <p>{formErrors.city}</p>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="city"
              name="city"
              value={city}
              onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-6">
            <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">
              Email
            </label>
            <p>{formErrors.email}</p>
            <input
              type="email"
              className="form-control"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="col-12 pt-4 text-center">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
              onClick={updateUser} 
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </div>

          <div className="col-12 pt-1 text-center">
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn btn-lg"
              
              >
                <a href="edit/password" className="text-decoration-none">
                Change Password
                </a>
              </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `user` as a dependency to the `useEffect`'s `dependency array`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      navigate('/')
    } else {
      checkUser();
    }
  }, [user]);
```